# Airflow list dag times out exactly after 30 seconds

Tags: timeout, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a dynamic airflow dag(`backfill_dag`) that basically reads admin variable(Json) and builds it self. `Backfill_dag` is used for backfilling/history loading, so for example if I wants to history load dag x,y, n z in some order(x n y run in parallel, z depends on x) then I will mention this in a particular json format and put it in admin variable of `backfill_dag`.

`Backfill_dag` now:

parses the Json, 
renders the tasks of the dags x,y, and z, and 
builds itself dynamically with x and y in parallel and z depends on x

Issue:

It works good as long as `Backfill_dag` can list_dags in 30 seconds.
Since `Backfill_dag` is bit complex here, it takes more than 30 seconds to list(airflow list_dags -sd Backfill_dag.py), hence it times out and the dag breaks.

Tried:

I tried to set a parameter, `dagbag_import_timeout = 100`, in `airflow.cfg` file of the scheduler, but that did not help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add log output and the DAG code.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my code.

Fix:
I had some aws s3 cp command in my dag that were running durring compilation hence my list_dags command was taking more than 30 seconds, i removed them(or had then in a BashOperator task), now my code compiles(list_dags) in couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Besides fixing your code you can also increase the `core.dagbag_import_timeout` which has per default 30 seconds. For me it helped increasing it to 150.

**core.dagbag_import_timeout**

default 30 seconds

The number of seconds before importing a Python file times out.

You can use this option to free up resources by increasing the time it takes before the Scheduler times out while importing a Python file to extract the DAG objects. This option is processed as part of the Scheduler "loop," and must contain a value lower than the value specified in core.dag_file_processor_timeout.

**core.dag_file_processor_timeout**

default: 50 seconds

The number of seconds before the DagFileProcessor times out processing a DAG file.

You can use this option to free up resources by increasing the time it takes before the DagFileProcessor times out. We recommend increasing this value if you're seeing timeouts in your DAG processing logs that result in no viable DAGs being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can try change other airflow configs like:
AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__WEB_SERVER_WORKER_TIMEOUT
AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TASK_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT

also as mentioned above:
AIRFLOW__CORE__DAG_FILE_PROCESSOR_TIMEOUT
AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGBAG_IMPORT_TIMEOUT